# Which programs use TeX's math syntax?

Tags: big-list

I'm trying to assemble a list of programs and online services which use (a subset of) TeX's mathematical syntax without being or requiring a classic TeX installation.  What I already have on my list:

- There are online services like [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) (merged with ShareLaTeX), [Papeeria](https://papeeria.com/), and [Authorea](https://www.authorea.com/) which offer collaborative editing of documents in the browser and either work like a full offline LaTeX distribution or support some mixture of Markdown and TeX syntax.  Did I miss any?
- There's [a LaTeX extension](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076) for Google Docs.
- I can't check because I don't have Microsoft Word, but apparently [it understands TeX syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8).
- We have at least two JavaScript libraries which deploy TeX syntax to display math in the browser, [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) and [KaTeX](https://katex.org/).
- MathJax is in turn used by [several Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax).
- The learning management system [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) can be configured to support TeX-style formulas.
- [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebooks can display math using MathJax.
- The computer algebra system [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) "understands" TeX syntax to a certain extent.
- The Möbius courseware system (formerly Maple TA) [seems to understand TeX syntax](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Mobius/MobiusInstructor/ch09s06.aspx).

Are there any mistakes in this list?  What else is out there?  I'd rather not count software like [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) for Microsoft PowerPoint as you need to have a TeX distribution installed to use it.

Comment: matplotlib can render TeX formulas. The PDF viewer Okular supports `$$ ... $$` syntax in annotations and can call LaTeX to render them. I believe Inkscape has some way (plugin?) to have formulas using LaTeX syntax.

Comment: Maybe geogebra also ? An certainly Matlab / Octave

Comment: There are some terminology issues with your list - Overleaf does not 'emulate' full LaTeX, it _is_ full LaTeX, it just runs on a server so you don't have to install a distribution on your own machine (a similar idea is [VerbTeX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=verbosus.verbtex) for Android). And MathJax is used by many, many websites/browser-based tools (over 90.000 according to https://trends.builtwith.com/websitelist/MathJax). But many features of LaTeX are not supported by MathJax, so to say that MathJax uses LaTeX math syntax is not entirely accurate.

Comment: The table on the [Formula editor Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor) has a “TeX support” column.

Comment: Google Docs has an equation editor which understands a lot of LaTeX commands (comparable to MS Word's, I think).  I'm curious as to the LaTeX extension that you link to - does it send the code off to a server and get it rendered as an image?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I haven't tried it myself, but the docs say: "The application needs to fetch images from CodeCogs/TeXRendr/Roger's renderer."

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, iOS and ipadOS, Pages (and also iBook Author on macOS) can insert an "Equation", with very basic and poor refinement.

https://www.apple.com/pages/

And also on iCloud :

https://www.icloud.com

With about 1,5 billion active devices under iOS and ipadOS, and perhaps 250 millions under macOS, that's a lot.